# Parity self correcting code

Tags: digital-logic

I am preparing for an exam in gates. I have a question regarding digital electronics.

Decimal number 5 in level parity self correcting code

- A) 00101
- B) 01011
- C) 01100
- D) 10000

The provided answer is 01011. How can I conclude this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework style question with no attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean "even" parity rather than "level" - the left bit is the parity bit and the remaining 4 bits form the number 5 (0101). If the number of bits in the remaining 4 bits is "even" then the left bit is unset. Does this make sense now?

Note that I'm trying hard not to feed this answer on a plate to the questioner!

Comment: So according to you answer is 00101 ?

Comment: Yes it is and I can't rationalize this with your given answer of 01011 - it's not unknown that given answers are wrong!

Comment: If you assume odd parity and write the parity bit after the value, you get the specified `0101 1`.  Since "even" wasn't specified in the question, this seems possible.

Comment: @BenVoigt good call

Comment: ... but this is in no way a "self correcting" code. At best, it's an error-detecting code.

Comment: @DaveTweed I agree, so now that's two areas in the question that are debatable; the title and the "provided answer"